# FBA users in People picker

Tags: people-picker

1. Intranet Portal 
   • For internal / AD users.
   Central Admin > Application Management > Manage web applications > Web Application > Authentication Providers > Default > Claim Authentication Type >
   Checked – Enable Windows Authentication
   Checked – Integrated Windows Authentication (NTLM from drop down)
   Checked – Basic Authentication
2. Extranet Portal 
   • For vendors / external users (extended web application of above intranet portal)
   Central Admin > Application Management > Manage web applications > Web Application > Authentication Providers > Extranet > Claim Authentication Type >
   Checked – Enable Form Based Authentication

If someone from AD / Intranet user want to assign a task to any external user or vendor from internal / intranet site so he can’t similarly if someone from the vendor want to assign a task from external site  to any AD user he can’t.
 Means, in people picker FBA users are not working in intranet site and similarly AD users are not coming in people picker of FBA site / extranet portal.

Note:

AD users are working on Intranet site and FBA users are working on extranet site in people picker.

I don’t want to enable both (Windows and FBA) authentication on default provider.

Is there any workaround to get FBA users in people picker of windows enabled site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Until and unless you define the FBA Authentication on your Intranet Portal as authentication provider; you can't use FBA users in People Picker.. Same case for Extranet portal

Comment: Thanks Arsalan for the prompt response, I have enabled both authentication on default zone and on extranet zone, now people picker issue has been resolved but when I want to open any document library on windows explorer it showing me a error "---------------------------
Message from webpage
---------------------------
Your client does not support opening this list with Windows Explorer.
---------------------------
". and I am using SharePoint app in Android and IOS. when I enabled FBA on a defualt zone authentication error occurred.

Comment: @HaseebChishti create a new question for that pls!

Comment: Please select the answer if it helped you, and close the question :)